# Images not showing on web page

Tags: image, canvas, web

I've created a web application that displays images in an html canvas control.  When I run the web page as localhost on the same server where the web application is installed, the images display fine.  When I run the web page from a client machine (not from the server where the web app is installed), the images do not display in the canvas.  Can someone explain why?  I have tried this in IE, Chrome and Firefox on the client machine and the image does not display in any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer was that the application pool the web site was running under was using the default ApplicationPoolIdentity, which gave the web site access to the images from the local machine but did not give the web site access to the images from client machines.  Changing the identity to an administrative account solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify absolute path.

If you website is india.com, you images referenced should be ./image.png or ./images/image.png

So that your server can reference it.

For more information, use firebug or chrome dev tool bar. In console you can see the reason.

Comment: This was a permission issue.  The web site didn't have permission to stream the images back due to the application pool identity setting. See below for the solution.